# Como usar uma tag customizada dentro de uma tag IF?

Tags: html, python, django-templates

Pessoal como uso uma tag customizada dentro de uma tag if?

```
ex:  {% if {%outraTag  x y z %} == "Sucesso" %}
```

meu custom_field_tag

```
@register.simple_tag
def outraTag(x,y,z):
  r=x+y+z
  if r ==3:
    return "Sucesso"
  else:
    return "Errado"
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja perguntando sobre JINJA, a linguagem de template do DJango. E o desejo seja usar uma tag HTML diferente dependendo de uma condição

Simplesmente use algo como:

```
<ul>
  {% if athlete_list %}
    {% for athlete in athlete_list %}
      <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <li>Sorry, no athletes in this list.</li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Retirado da [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) do DJango

De mesma sorte, você poderia usar

```
{% if condicao %}
   <H1>
{% else %}
   <H2>
{% endif %}
   Qualquer coisa
{% if condicao %}
   </H1>
{% else %}
   </H2>
{% endif %}
```

Esta solução me parece um pouco estranha, porém não conheço o seu projeto e pode resolver sua questão.